# Read Outlook messages with JS app?

Tags: javascript, oauth, outlook, imap

### I would like to access a user's Outlook emails with my javascript app.

Google makes this very easy using Oauth and it's restful [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/).

I have tried researching similar options for Outlook, but I can't seem to find a good way to authenticate a user with Oauth 2.0, then access their message inbox.

Are there any Microsoft technology experts that can point me to some resources to get started here?

I am restricted to using only client-side code as this is for a phonegap mobile application. I would like to continue using [`oauth-io`](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js) but I realize that may not be an option.

Comment: Do you mean *Exchange* email?  Outlook is a client.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time tracking down the process for getting the emails as well. Anyway, first things first, you'd need to register your app for OAuth [here](https://account.live.com/developers/applications). This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-user-authentication-oauth-guide.aspx#registerapplication) describes some more details on the registration and also how to access the needed API.

Although you can do the calls via Javascript, there are some security issues because you'd eventually need to send your client secret. It might be safer to do some parts in the server side.

First step is getting the user to login and retrieving the access token.

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&scope=wl.imap wl.offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]
```

On the server side, exchange the access code for an access token:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]&code=[ACCES_CODE]&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]
```

Get user's email and other account info ([Python sample codes](http://chriskief.com/2013/01/05/register-with-oauth-microsoft-live/)):

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]
```

Retrieve emails via IMAP using the email address from emails>preferences in previous reply (see more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx)). It would look something like this in Python:

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
username = [username]
access_token = [access_token]
auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (username, access_token)
mail.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
mail.list()
```

You can look at existing IMAP libraries to retrieve the actual emails from there. Here's one for [python](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/).